# ls there an equivalent in French for "scare quotes"?

Tags: traduction, typographie

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scare_quotes) defines *scare quotes* as

> quotation marks that writers place around a word or phrase to signal
> that they are using it in an ironic, referential, or otherwise
> non-standard sense [and] may indicate that the author is using someone
> else's term, similar to preceding a phrase with the expression
> "so-called"; they may imply skepticism or disagreement, belief that
> the words are misused, or that the writer intends a meaning opposite
> to the words enclosed in quotes.

My Robert disclaims all knowledge of the phrase, and the closest my Larousse has to offer is *entre guillemets*: but that can most directly be rendered as "in quotation marks", which says nothing about why the writer put them there, the way "in scare quotes" explicitly does.

Answer (score 10):

They can be called:

- ***[Guillemets d'ironie](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guillemet#Guillemets_d%27ironie)***
- ***Guillemets de distanciation***

***Entre guillemets*** is actually a good translation of scare quotes. When we use the expression ***entre guillemets***, we normally refer to them. This can even be done in written form without using actual quotes:

> *De mon côté, j’ai toujours ressenti et apprécié cette liberté de choisir ce que je voulais faire de ma vie. Liberté **entre guillemets** car il y a d’indispensables et d’inévitables règles de vie à observer.*
> Martine Camus, *La saga Villeneuve : une dynastie québécoise en F1*

Otherwise, we prefer to wrap the quoted text with ***je cite*** (I quote) and ***fin de citation*** (end of quote) or, especially in a school-dictation context, ***deux points, ouvrez les guillemets***.

Answer (score 4):

The term used to translate  "square quote" is "guillemets d'ironie" also called "guillmets ironiques" ; however, it is not a term that ecompasses the whole range of the contexts of use, since "irony" is not necessarily involved.

> ([Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guillemet#Usage_en_fran%C3%A7ais)) **Guillemets d'ironie**
>
> Les guillemets d’ironie, dits aussi guillemets ironiques, désignent une utilisation particulière des guillemets pour indiquer que le terme ou l’expression mis en exergue n’a pas sa signification littérale ou habituelle et n’est pas nécessairement cité d’une autre source. Les guillemets d’ironie marquent la distance, l’ironie, le mépris que l’auteur veut montrer vis-à-vis de ce qu’il cite. Ils ont un pouvoir de distanciation et indiquent les réserves de l’auteur par rapport à un mot ou à une expression29. Leur nom anglais est « scare quotes ».
>
> Le linguiste Jacques Drillon écrit : « Les guillemets ont deux fonctions principales : on les emploie pour citer, mais on les emploie aussi pour se désolidariser de ce qu’on dit, pour ajouter une distance, une nuance d’ironie ou d’étrangeté26. »

Another term seems preferable to French Canadians; it's the term "*guillemet de distanciation*" and it does not have the defect found in the term shown above. It can be noticed that it picks up on the the central idea considered in the explanation ("distance").

> ([Termium](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=&index=ent&srchtxt=SCARE%20QUOTES))
> **guillemets de distanciation**
> , nom masculin pluriel
>
> **guillemets de mise à distance**
> nom masculin pluriel
> [Par l'emploi de] guillemets de mise à distance[,] le rédacteur signale une expression ou un mot dont il veut se distancier et, par conséquent, amène le lecteur à y porter attention.

Comment: *it is not a term that ecompasses the whole range of the contexts of use, since "irony" is not necessarily involved* Well, scare is even less encompassing the range of contexts of scare quotes.

Comment: @jlliagre Two wrongs do not make a right, but I agree, the English term has a similar defect.

Answer (score 2):

Les guillemets peuvent être employés pour fins de [*mise à distance*](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/23391/la-ponctuation/guillemets/guillemets-et-mise-en-evidence). Il s'agit néanmoins toujours simplement de *guillemets* :

> Les guillemets jouent deux grands rôles : marquer le discours rapporté
> (citations et discours directs) et mettre en valeur ou à distance un
> mot ou un groupe de mots. Ces deux grandes fonctions se subdivisent en
> plusieurs emplois plus particuliers. ([BDL](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/23363/la-ponctuation/guillemets/generalites-sur-les-guillemets))

La complémentation du nom *guillemet* n'a pas vocation à le nommer mais plutôt à en expliquer la fonction ou le rôle. Le nom composé est superfétatoire à mon avis.

---

> *L'auteur a employé les guillemets pour mettre à distance (le terme
> etc.).*

Comment: _Guillemets-épouvantail_ !